# How do I pull up a 24FPS audio mix for a 25FPS video timeline in Nuendo?

Tags: film, nuendo, dubbing

OK so there must be a simple way of doing this but for the life of me...

I am working in Nuendo 10. I have completed a mix for the original 24FPS film, but the client has decided she wants to submit to festivals at 25FPS. I can easily go into "Project Settings" and set up the "Project Audio Pull" to 4.1667% which - as expected, shortens the overall timeline by the required amount.

However, when I come to export this new timeline, the resulting file is exactly the same as the original 24FPS audio stripe.

There has to be a simple way of doing this.... surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I finally worked this out.

Select the audio region to pull-up. 
F7 for "Direct Offline Processing"

[image]

Add a "Time Stretch" effect.

Select a ratio of 96 (96%).

This will shorten the region by 4%

Use an algorithm of Elastique-Pro-Time.

Apply the effect and Export region at the new length.